# Dominated convergence theorem on Lebesgue's integral

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-integral

Let $\psi^n_t$  be a sequence of stochastic process that converge for all $t$ to $\psi_t$ a.s., namely $\psi^n_t \to\psi_t$.
In the following case, for bringing inside the limit, is it necessary applying some convergence theorem, as for example, the lebesgue's dominated convergence? 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^t\psi_s^nds$$ and concluding that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^t\psi_s^nds \to\int_0^t\psi_sds  $$

Which are the condition that has to be satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

That there exists a stochastic process $\varphi$ such that $|\psi^n_s|\leq \varphi_s$ for every $s$ and $\varphi\in L^1([0,T])$ for every event. If you only want the limit to hold almost surely, you can replace all of the above identities appropriately.

This, of course, not *necessary*, but probably the most general theorem that is generally applicable.

Alternatively, if  $\psi^n\to \psi$ in $L^1([0,T]\times \Omega),$ then you get the desired by Fubini's theorem, but this requires additional measurability assumptions.